# What is the bijection between $ \text{Hom}(M\otimes_RN,P)$ and $\text{Hom}_R(M,\text{Hom}_R(N,P)) $?

Tags: tensor-products

I try to find a bijection between $Hom_R (M \otimes_R N, P)$ and $Hom_R (M, Hom_R (N,P))$

where $M$, $N$ and $P$ are modules over a ring $R$ and $\otimes_R$ is the tensor product of $R$-modules.
I think we can somehow use the universal property of the tensor product, but I don't see how to do that exactly.

Later I will need this bijection to show that $.\otimes_R M$ is a right exact additive covariant functor, but if you could just give me a hint for the first part of the question I might figure this out on my own.

Comment: Actually now I have problems with the second part of the question. How can I use this bijection to show that the funcor is right exact and additive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that a map $f$ in $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, \operatorname{Hom}_R(N, P))$ can be seen as a bilinear map $g: M \times N \to P$. This correspondence is given by:
$$
f(m)(n) = g(m, n).
$$
It is an easy check that this is indeed well-defined.

The universal property of the tensor product now directly gives you the bijection you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to build the desired isomorphism by using the isomorphism between $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$ and $U \otimes V^*$, where $V^* = \operatorname{Hom}(V,R)$. In particular, we have
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(M \otimes N,P) \cong\\
(M \otimes N)^*\otimes P \cong \\
(M^* \otimes N^*) \otimes P \cong\\
M^* \otimes (N^*\otimes P) \cong \\
\operatorname{Hom}(M,(N^* \otimes P)) \cong\\
\operatorname{Hom}(M,\operatorname{Hom}(N, P)).
$$